# Display list of most used tags in the last 30 days

Tags: tags, recent-posts

I am looking for a way to display the most used tags over the last 30 days. I am no coder, but I have come up with this mashup to display a list of the most used 28 tags (preference to fit my theme). I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to limit the tags to the most used in the last 30 days.

Here is what I have:

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
    <?php
        $tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number'=>28) );
            foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
            }
    ?>
</ul>
```

### Update

This is the full code I am using right now, following One Trick Pony's code below.

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
   SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id
      WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

The website is slightly less than ~4 weeks old, so to test, I changed `INTERVAL 30 DAY` to `INTERVAL 3 DAY` and the tags being returned seem random and some haven't been used in 2+ weeks and have only been used a single time. As well, only 8 tags are being displayed, when more have been used.

To check that the correct number of days have been queried, I did the following:

Completely deleted all items in the trash for posts and pages, I don't have any custom post types.

Did the same with drafts.

Ran a query in phpmyadmin to delete all post revisions - `DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";`

Ran a query in phpmyadmin to check if the results are the posts from the last 3 days - `SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= post_date`

The results from the phpmyadmin query were, in fact, the posts from the last 3 days, but the front-end display did not change.

## Update 2

Here are some screen shots. Maybe the screenshots can help find where my code is wrong.

**Blog Post with Category and Tags**

[image: Image of blog post]

**`wp_posts` table with the post `ID` of above post**

[image: wp_posts]

**`wp_terms` table with the `term_id` of the tags used**

[image: wp_terms]

**`wp_term_taxonomy` with the tags' `term_id` as `term_taxonomy_id`**

[image: wp_term_taxonomy]

**`wp_term_relationships` with `term_taxonomy_id` assigned to post as `object_id`**

[image: wp_term_relationships]

## Update 3

I think I figured out the problem, but do not know how to fix it.

The SQL query gets the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID and `get_tag_link` uses `term_id`

Comment: Updated with new full code and procedures followed and tasks completed to check for errors.

Comment: Does the code above need the WordPress tables prefix or does wpdb already take that into consideration? When I add the prefix to the tables in the code. Nothing at all is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the SQL query code was getting the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID.

I added an additional INNER JOIN using the `term_taxonomy` table to get the `term_id`.  This seems to work, but if a mod can improve this, please do!

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not working for me on WP 4.8.2

Answer (score 1):

This query should help you get you the term IDs used by posts from the last 30 days:

```
SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships    
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id    
  WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date
```

Then you pass these IDs to the "include" argument of `get_tags()`

---

Full code:

```
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
   SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id
      WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if($term_ids > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));

  // your foreach loop here...

}else{
  print 'no posts were tagged in the last 30 days';

}
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do this though.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I changed `INTERVAL 30 DAY` to `INTERVAL 3 DAY` to test it out. I left the number of tags at 28. 11 tags were pulled. Today is April 11 - The tags pulled by the function were last used on - 4/9, 4/11, 4/10, 4/2, 4/2, 3/31, 4/2, 4/3, 4/3, 4/6

Comment: Did a quick test and seems to work on my setup. Maybe you have newer posts in the trash that are using some of those tags? The query above doesn't differentiate between post status or post type.

Comment: I have emptied the trash. I have no custom post types. I have three drafts, their last update dates are: 4/7, 4/5, 4/2. Now 9 tags are being displayed. Here is the complete code I am using (minus CSS, of course)

Comment: `<ul id="footer-tags">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
   SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id
      WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if($term_ids > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>`

Comment: Sorry, that feels like I just broke a rule... Sorry, I am new here. Let me know the correct method, if I did.

Comment: First, it should be `if(count($term_ids) > 0)`, my mistake there :) But that's not the problem. Try getting all posts from the last 3 days, run a query in phpmyadmin, it's easier: `SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= post_date` and see if the results are posts from the last 3 days...

Comment: First, I changed the code to `if(count($term_ids) > 0)` Next, I deleted all post revisions using `DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";` I then ran the query you mention. It appears to be getting all the posts from the last 3 days only.

Comment: I have added an update to the question, maybe we can find the problem in the code.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, but do not know how to fix it.

The SQL query gets the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID and `get_tag_link` uses `term_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit tags using "number" parameter...

```
 $tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC','number'=>28) );
```

For reference to get_tags function read this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Comment: This limits the number of tags, not the number of days to determine popularity.

Comment: Stephen is correct, although it is a cleaner way of limiting the number of tags. I edited the code. Still looking for a solution to limit the most popular in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `get_tags->count` does not really count the tags in a range. I have implemented this solution, please let me know if this works for you:

```
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT term_id , count(*) cont FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date AND  $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy='post_tag'
    GROUP BY term_id
    ORDER BY cont DESC
    LIMIT 5
");    
if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
    $tags = get_tags( array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'number'  => 5,
        'include' => $term_ids,
    ) );
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . 
            $tag->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `get_tags` now when you already have 5 tags order by count ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked, But I think performance isn't good.

```
global $wpdb;

$limit = 10;

$sql      = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'digi_posts' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date";
            $sql      = "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE object_id in ($sql) GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id ORDER BY COUNT(term_taxonomy_id) DESC";
            $sql      = "SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND term_taxonomy_id in ($sql) LIMIT {$limit}";
            $term_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );

if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
    $tags = get_tags( array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'number'  => $limit,
        'include' => $term_ids,
    ) );
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . 
            $tag->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```