# What is the difference between terms and tags?

Tags: tags, terms

I am working on a problem to get the [most recently used tags within the last 30 days](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/display-list-of-most-used-tags-in-the-last-30-days).

My current thought process is not working, so I am trying to come up with an alternative method.

I came across [get_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) and [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), thinking they may be a way to an actual functioning solution to my problem.

However, searching for "What is the difference between terms and tags in WordPress" is too general and I cannot find an answer.

What is the difference between tags and terms? It what situations would get_term or get_terms be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple yet tough question, taxonomies are just groups of categories, while terms are just single categories within these groups.*

So, for example, if you create a new post and choose category for it - the category itself is a term, and opening `YourWordpressURL/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` you're going to see all the categories (taxonomy).

Terms and Tags are similar at first glance, they just work differently:

http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2005/09/09/categories-versus-tags-whats-the-difference-and-which-one/

http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/10/17/categories-vs-tags/

*this is possibly sometimes not true, as terms don't have to be categories, but I hate word "terms", it just confuses me, categories fits better

Comment: Wordpressor and @kaiser thanks for both of your answers. It really is a simple answer, but seemingly difficult to explain. After this answer, I went into the DB structure and looked through `wp_terms`, `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` of my familiar website. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In general *everything* is a »Taxonomy«:

- category
- term
- link_category
- terms...

But there's also the difference between "hierarchical" and non-hierarchical (a.k.a. flat) Taxonomies - I guess I don't have to explain that.

Comment: Ok, but, what exactly is a is a term?

Comment: A taxonomy name, like category or such. It equals to (for ex.) a `tag`.

Comment: So, a term is everything that is a taxonomy?

Comment: `term` is just a name for a specified `taxonomy`. Like `category`. WP uses this internally to say "it´s a flat/non-hierachical custom taxonomy type". The only _official_ word is "Taxonomy". Nothing else.