# Get the latest tags in a cloud?

Tags: tags

Is there something that allows us to get a list of the latest tags used in post.

I want to get the 10 latest tags and align them side by side

How Can I make this happen?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66730/displaying-the-most-recently-used-tags/66735#66735

Comment: @OneTrickPony You can mark posts as duplicates if you think the _exact_ same answer would solve the problem.

Comment: but this one is older than the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The default WordPress tag cloud cannot order by latest, it only works by displaying the "most used", it does not accept any parameters to alter the query, only the layout.

Tags are usually used in conjunction with posts and are not really meant to be an archive or category, so in order to display the latest tags I'm pretty certain you have to do a direct DB query.

References in how to use WPDB to retrieve latest tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972525/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-most-recent-tags-in-a-wordpress-database

[Display list of most used tags in the last 30 days](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/display-list-of-most-used-tags-in-the-last-30-days)