# Displaying the most recently used tags

Tags: tags

Is it possible to just show the most recent tags from e.g. the latest 10 posts as a tag cloud?

The only things that I found were the [WP Recent Tags plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-recent-tags/) which is a bit outdated and no tags are displayed when I use the widget.

I found the following posts:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972525/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-most-recent-tags-in-a-wordpress-database
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104947/get-recent-tags-in-wordpress

But they don’t work for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just feed your tag list to [wp_generate_tag_cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_tag_cloud):

```
$found_tags = $final_tags = $id_records = array();

// get last 10 posts
$last_posts = get_posts('numberposts=10');

// gather tags
foreach($last_posts as $post)
  $found_tags = array_merge($found_tags, wp_get_post_tags($post->ID));

// prepare final tags for the cloud
foreach($found_tags as $tag){

  // ignore duplicates
  if(in_array($tag->term_id, $id_records))
    continue;

  // track ids...
  $id_records[] = $tag->term_id;

  // generate links
  $tag->link = get_tag_link($tag);

  // keep it
  $final_tags[] = $tag;
}

// feed to the cloud
print wp_generate_tag_cloud($final_tags);
```

You might want to cache this, because it makes quite a few queries

Comment: Thank you very much—works like a charm! Just another short question: Is it possible to sort the tags by count and not by name?

Comment: I just found out how to sort the tags by count: Changing the last line to `print wp_generate_tag_cloud($final_tags, array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC'));` will do it.

Comment: That first line tho... I didn't know you could do that but it makes perfect sense for defining variables.