# Get TOP x Tags from selected posts

Tags: tags

I need help on this, the case is I want to get TOP X tags from user post.
For example user A wrote 50 post, i want to show TOP 5 tags from that user post,
It 's for displaying user interest.

second important thing is i m already have the post ID's selected.
$pids = array(123,345,323,456,789);

Thank you.

- i found interesting code here, but just by date: [Display list of most used tags in the last 30 days](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/display-list-of-most-used-tags-in-the-last-30-days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an array containing the post IDs its easy

```
$post_ids = array( 167, 774, 787, 358 );
$tag_all  = array();

foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, array() );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag )
        array_push( $tag_all, $tag->name );
}

$result = array_count_values($tag_all);
arsort( $result );
$result = array_slice( $result, 0, 5 );

echo '<ol>';
foreach ( $result as $tag => $count ) {
    printf( '<li>%s (%d)</li>', $tag, $count );
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Walk over the post IDs, get the tags of each post. Add the tags to a result array (`$tag_all`). Then counting the values (`array_count_values()`), this gives you an array with `key => value` (`key` = tag, `value`= count). Now just sorting the result array (`arsort()`) and get the first 5 elements (`array_slice()`).
Create a nice outpout and finish.

Comment: Thank you! it's working smooth :)
* just wondering/possibility using one query *