# How to add chunk of php, html, and sql code to variable an append to $content

Tags: plugin-development, sql, variables

I am creating a plugin (my first) which allows the site admin to display the most used post tags over the last X number of days. This plugin is an evolution of the WP Development question here - [Display list of most used tags in the last 30 days](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/display-list-of-most-used-tags-in-the-last-30-days).

Forgive me for not knowing the proper jargon.

I have most of the leg-work completed with the admin menu, etc, the only thing I have left is to actually display the results.

The following snippet of code works when I drop it into the single.php file.

```
<div class="recent-popular-tags">
<h3><?php echo $rpt_options['heading_tags']; ?></h3>
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php
global $rpt_options;
$rpt_days = $rpt_options['number_days'];
global $wpdb;
$rpt_term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $rpt_days DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($rpt_term_ids) > 0){

  $rpt_tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => $rpt_options['number_tags'],
    'include' => $rpt_term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $rpt_tags as $rpt_tag ) {
echo '<span class="rpt-link"><a href="' . get_tag_link ($rpt_tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $rpt_tag->name . '</a></span>';
}
}
?>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UzzXPFk.png]

I'm stuck at converting this code to a variable to append to `$content`.

Right now, I only have a very simply display function, to test that the `number_days` and `number_tags` settings will display the values entered into the settings page. They do.

```
function rpt_display_content ($content){

global $rpt_options;

if(is_single()){    

    $rpt_display = '<p>' . $rpt_options['rpt_tags_days'] . $rpt_options['rpt_tags_number'] . '</p>';    

    $content .= $rpt_display;
}

return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rpt_display_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be quite close to having this all sorted out. If you wrap your queries in a function, and separate the logic and presentation:

```
<?php 
function wpse_158425_get_terms(){
    global $wpdb, $rpt_options;

    $wpdb->show_errors();

    $rpt_days = $rpt_options['number_days'];

    $rpt_term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $rpt_days DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date
        ");

        if(count($rpt_term_ids) > 0){

          $rpt_tags = get_tags(array(
            'orderby' => 'count',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'number'  => $rpt_options['number_tags'],
            'include' => $rpt_term_ids,
          ));

        } else {
            $rpt_tags = FALSE;
        }

        return $rpt_tags;

}

function wpse_158425_display_terms(){
    global $rpt_options;

    $tags = wpse_158425_get_terms();

    $recentTags = '<div class="recent-popular-tags">';

    $recentTags .= '<h3>'.$rpt_options['heading_tags'].'</h3>';

    if($tags != FALSE){
        foreach($tags as $tag){
           $recentTags .= '<span class="rpt-link"><a href="' . get_tag_link ($rpt_tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $rpt_tag->name . '</a></span>';
        }
    } else {
            $recentTags .= 'There are no popular tags right now.';
    }

    $recentTags .= '</div><!--.recent-popular-tags-->';

    return $recentTags;

}

function rpt_display_content ($content){

    if(is_single()){    

        $rpt_display = wpse_158425_display_terms();    

        $content .= $rpt_display;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rpt_display_content');

?>
```

You can further simplify this by making `wpse_158245_get_terms()` accept variables and passing the options in that manner, and setting default variables.

I did not have a chance to run this, you might run into some object/array errors, but you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Aris, thanks for the reply. I have not tried it, because shortly after posting, I remembered a tip I had learned and figured out a solution - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154862/14558 - I am not sure which is better or why... Can you take a look and tell me which and why?

Comment: These solutions are extremely similar. Your solution solves one very specific problem, with one specific solution. The multi-function option solves for a variety of uses, and allows for a variety of outputs.

The biggest single factor is that you could extend the multi-function way to put your terms into a transient (cached into the database), thereby increasing performance dramatically. You can do so with the single function, but it will become even more dense.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it works exactly as expected. Being a novice, is this a better solution than the [solution posted by Aris Blevins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154849/14558)? If not, why?

I honestly do not know.

```
<?php

/***** Display Functions *******/    
function rpt_display_content ($content){

global $rpt_options;

if(is_single()){    

    ob_start();

?>

<div class="recent-popular-tags">
<h3><?php echo $rpt_options['heading_tags']; ?></h3>
    <?php
    $rpt_days = $rpt_options['number_days'];
    global $wpdb;
    $rpt_term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $rpt_days DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

    if(count($rpt_term_ids) > 0){

      $rpt_tags = get_tags(array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'number'  => $rpt_options['number_tags'],
        'include' => $rpt_term_ids,
      ));
    foreach ( (array) $rpt_tags as $rpt_tag ) {
    echo '<span class="rpt-link"><a href="' . get_tag_link ($rpt_tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $rpt_tag->name . '</a></span>';
    }
    }
    ?>
</div>  

<?php

$content .= ob_get_clean();
}

return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'rpt_display_content');
?>
```